# not able to use jquery .append(data) as .val(append(data))

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use JQuery `.append(data)` on success to use that to change value of an input to that append data as : `.val(append(data))` but is not working while I can successfully change value to a string as `.val("Hello")` instead of changing value to append data..!
so if anyone can help please..!
Here is the full code too as :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('.upload').on('submit', (function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".no_image").css("display", "none"),
                    $(".show_image").css("display", "block"),
                    $(".profile_photo").val(append(data)),
                    $(".image").attr("src", "client_images/" + append(data));
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log("error");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }));

        $(".inputFile").on("change", function () {
            $(".upload").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

While form code is :

```
<div class="bgColor">
    <form id="uploadForm" class="upload" action="upload_image.php" method="post">
        <div id="targetLayer" class="target" style="width: 28%;height: 0%;">
            <div class="no_image" style="display:block;">No Image</div>
            <div class="show_image" style="display:none;">
                <img class="image" src="" width="100px" height="100px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="uploadFormLayer">
            <label>Upload Image File:</label>
            <br/>
            <input name="userImage" id="userImage" type="file" class="inputFile" />
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
<fieldset>
    <input name="profile_photo" class="profile_photo" type="text"/>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no global `append` function, `append` is a jQuery method, i.e. you can only call it on a jQuery object. If you want to append a string to the current value of the input you can use the `val`'s callback function:

```
// ...
$(".profile_photo").val(function(index, currentValue) {
    return currentValue + data;
});
// there is no need to call a non-existent `append` function
// for string concatenation, `+` does the trick
$(".image").attr("src", "client_images/" + data);
```

The `val` method's callback function is executed once for each element in the jQuery collection. The first parameter of the callback function is the `index` of the current iteration. The second parameter is the current value of the element. In the above code snippet the current value of the `input` is concatenated with the `data` variable. The returned value of the function is used for setting value of the element.

Comment: Can you clarify please little bit..I am new to these stuffs..what should I replace with `currentValue` and also `currentValue+data`?

Comment: Once again Thanks for clarification to use just `data` instead of `append(data)`